# Two cats are attacking another cat

Tags: cats, behavior

I was having a walk today with a friend and I saw two cats--one of them is young and the other old-- attacking another young cat.

The young cat was afraid and looking at both cats expecting the next attack, and they would attack the cat frequently.

After sometime, the young evil cat hopped on the cat and bited it from the back and the cat started screaming of pain --The other old cat would also do that, so we interfered and separated the cats and we then started to push the evil cats away and we did that.

After sometime, the small cat would show us her belly, and other time she would voluntary go to the other cats and get attacked again.

What is going on here?What should I have done? leave them? or interfere?

They are stray cats, but I just wanted to know why they do that.

Comment: It's a mating process, you should probably just leave them.

Comment: And cats don't get kittens just to be human companions, there is a purpose of cats in the world just like there is a purpose of people. If mating is really going to hurt the poor cat, then and only then you should consider spaying a stray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the young cat that showed you her belly might be in heat (estrous) and the other cats are trying to mate with her. Since they are strays, the very best thing you could do is take the young female and have her spayed. Stray animals that reproduce make more stray animals. Ask around your area, oftentimes you can find veterinarians who do low cost spay/neuter services and organizations who raise money to pay for surgeries--especially for feral or stray cats.

You are obviously a caring person, help this young kitten and reduce the population of unwanted companion animals. Thanks for caring!